# Android device background service issue

Tags: android

I am using Background service in our application:

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    handler.postDelayed(r, 5000);
    return START_STICKY;
}

Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.postDelayed(r, 5000);
        Log.d("arpit", "connected");
    }
};

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(Appclass.getInstance().getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());
    restartServiceIntent.setPackage(getPackageName());
    PendingIntent restartServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(Appclass.getInstance()
            .getApplicationContext(), 1, restartServiceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000, restartServicePendingIntent);
}
}
```

It's working fine, and also works if I close or kill the application.
but on some devices like `oppo A33F` , `Lenovo Vibe K5` etc push notification is not getting through, and also the service class is destroyed after killing the application. I checked in `running application` section of device but my application is not showing by which means service class is destroyed, after killed the application. How can I resolved this and keep my service continuously running even after the app is killed.

Comment: if your service's work is that important, use a foreground service

Comment: This service will be stopped after 1 minute on Android 8.0+, so you need to revisit your strategy anyway. Beyond that, some devices have their "killing" behave akin to the Force Stop button in Settings, and there is nothing that you can do about that.

Comment: How can i resolved this? i need solution. And without click on stop button in setting option, service stopping after an kill app.